# Opening an OpenDialog from Vis C++ console app?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I know this is a darn simple question, but I'm very used to using Borland and wrappers, so this is a bit of a new approach for me. Can someone simply tell me how I Can open an OpenDialog that only gets .obj files from a visual studio c++ console app?

It's very much appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question you might get better responses if it's a bit clearer. If it's a console app rather than a windows app I don't think you'll be able to open the OpenDialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't really any difference between a console application and a GUI application, except for entry point (WinMain in a 'GUI' app), and a console app will have a console window opened during startup if not started from a console.

All of the Win32 API is available, so you need to use the [GetOpenFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646927.aspx) call, as follows:

#define DEFAULT_EXTENSION L".obj"

```
OPENFILENAME    ofn;
wchar_t *FilterSpec =L"Object Files(*.obj)\0*.obj\0Text Files(*.txt)\0*.txt\0All Files(*.*)\0*.*\0";
wchar_t *Title =L"Open....";
wchar_t szFileName[MAX_PATH];
wchar_t szFileTitle[MAX_PATH];
int             Result;
wchar_t filePath[MAX_PATH]; // Selected file and path

*szFileName = 0;
*szFileTitle = 0;

/* fill in non-variant fields of OPENFILENAME struct. */
ofn.lStructSize       = sizeof(OPENFILENAME);
ofn.hwndOwner         = GetFocus();
ofn.lpstrFilter       = FilterSpec;
ofn.lpstrCustomFilter = NULL;
ofn.nMaxCustFilter    = 0;
ofn.nFilterIndex      = 0;
ofn.lpstrFile         = szFileName;
ofn.nMaxFile          = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrInitialDir   = L"."; // Initial directory.
ofn.lpstrFileTitle    = szFileTitle;
ofn.nMaxFileTitle     = MAX_PATH;
ofn.lpstrTitle        = Title;
ofn.lpstrDefExt   =     DEFAULT_EXTENSION;

ofn.Flags             = OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST|OFN_HIDEREADONLY;

if (!GetOpenFileName ((LPOPENFILENAME)&ofn))
{
    return; // Failed or cancelled
}
else
{
    wcscpy_s(filePath,ofn.lpstrFile);
}
```

Comment: after some messing around with the code, that did 'er! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to open an OpenDialog from VC++ console app.

Steps:
Create a new project. -> select Win32 Console Application.
In the next dialog, select "An Application that supports MFC".
you will be provided with the following code:

#include "stdafx.h" 
#include "test.h"

#ifdef _DEBUG 
#define new DEBUG_NEW 
#undef THIS_FILE 
static char THIS_FILE[] = __FILE__; 
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// The one and only application object

CWinApp theApp;

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[], TCHAR* envp[])
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

```
// initialize MFC and print and error on failure
if (!AfxWinInit(::GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, ::GetCommandLine(), 0))
{
    // TODO: change error code to suit your needs
    cerr << _T("Fatal Error: MFC initialization failed") << endl;
    nRetCode = 1;
}
else
{
    // TODO: code your application's behavior here.
    CString strHello;
    strHello.LoadString(IDS_HELLO);
    cout << (LPCTSTR)strHello << endl;
}

return nRetCode;
```

}

Add the following code at the begining of "else" part

CFileDialog dlgOpen(TRUE,NULL,NULL,OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,"Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt||");
dlgOpen.DoModal();

Run the application. A open dialog will be opened automatically. Google "CFileDialog" for further help.

Comment: not everyone wants to have MFC in their app - especially a console app!  Also - an existing app might not be so easy to convert to mfc...

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio one usually relies on [MFC's CFileDialog class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk77e5e7(VS.80).aspx). Take a look at linked MSDN documentation page for sample usage. This page has [some examples](http://funnotes.net/File-open-dialog-box-using-CFileDialog.php) as well.

If you are using Windows Vista or Windows 7, you can try the new COM interface [IFileOpenDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775834(VS.85).aspx). Kenny Kerr has a [nice article](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/11/10/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-6-_1320_-The-New-File-Dialogs.aspx) on using the new Vista dialogs.

Comment: not everyone wants to have MFC in their app - especially a console app!

Comment: Makes sense.
Use the GetOpenFileName() api call instead.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646829(VS.85).aspx